# How to configure two separate networks with one server two Nics?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

I have one server (win server 2012 R2) that have two NICs with two separate networks, my problem is I can't configure because network (B) has its internet connection from an modem  but network (A) not have internet connection the following image is example How can I configure the Network (B) using internet and access to share folders on server, also network (A) access to share folders on the same sever.

[image: Example of Network]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question is a bit confusing. First you state that you have a server that is already configured with two separate networks (via the two NICs), then you state that '....I can't configure because network (B) has ....'. Do you want to configure a share on the server? Do you want Network (A) to have internet access? Where are you situated: in the Internet or LAN? Please clarify your question and be a little bit more specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

- Make the **IP** on the server in **network A** as the gateway of all the hosts in network A.
- Have the default route on server towards the router(modem) IP in network B.
- Have a static route configured on the router in order to go to **network A**  go to next-hop **IP of network B** on the server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just wanted the network B can access to internet and access to shared folders on server but network A only can access to shared folders on server.

Comment: oops I flipped the network representation correcting it in answer!

Comment: If you have an extra port on network A you can directly connect it to router though forgot to add that!